# How to get a HEAD of a Retrofit call from an api endpoint that requires field in the request body?

Tags: android, http, retrofit2

I am trying to examine the headers of a response from an API call made via Retrofit 2.0.2 before actually downloading the content.

My API interface looks like the following:

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json", "Origin: http://www.example.com"})
@HEAD("profiles")
Call<Void> getProfileHeaders(@Field("puids") String puid);
```

Please note that the API call requires me to specify in the body a field called `puids=%{UUID}` list of UUIDs in order to return a response.

If I would like to download the data without examining the headers first, I would just call an interface like this:

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json", "Origin: http://www.example.com"})
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("profiles")
Call<String> getProfile(@Field("puids") String puid);
```

Now the issue is that when I try to use the `getProfileHeader()` endpoint, I get the following RuntimeException:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #1)
```

In order to use the @Field parameters (as I suppose a POST method would normally would do if required), I would have to explicitly specify that I use `@FormUrlEncoded`, but I can't make a `@HEAD` call with that.

I am a bit puzzled how could I achieve what I want and what am I missing?

**Basically I would like to know how can I examine a retrofit call's response headers before downloading the actual body, of an API endpoint that requires field parameters?**

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I just realized that my confusion originates from a couple of misunderstandings:

1. **`@HEAD` is an HTTP method to usually verify the hyperlinks validity and the server's response to a `GET` call. It does not work with `POST` request and it is theoretically incorrect.**

Taken from `RFC2616` of the HTTP/1.1 definitions:

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
>   return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained
>   in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical
>   to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can
>   be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the
>   request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is
>   often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility,
>   and recent modification.
>
> The response to a HEAD request MAY be cacheable in the sense that the
>   information contained in the response MAY be used to update a
>   previously cached entity from that resource. If the new field values
>   indicate that the cached entity differs from the current entity (as
>   would be indicated by a change in Content-Length, Content-MD5, ETag or
>   Last-Modified), then the cache MUST treat the cache entry as stale.

2. **When making a `POST` request by definition we already calculated the response server-side and taken the time to download the body in consideration.**

One of the function's of the `POST` method, as defined in `RFC2616` is:

> - Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a form, to a data-handling process;

Hence verifying the header in order not do download the body beats the purpose of this.

---

As mentioned by @Radek above, using interceptors on `GET` request to modify and/or examine requests on the fly would do the work, but at that point we could also initiate a `HEAD` method request.

**The solution to this problem would be to better align to the standard definitions defined in `RFC2616` by making changes on the server-side to instead of returning block of raw data as a POST response, make it to return a resource that would be than called in a `GET`/`HEAD` request then. All just refactor the service call to use `GET` instead of `POST`.**

Answer (score 2):

Okhttp which is used by retrofit has Interceptors which let you modify or examine requests on the fly. Check out the [github documentation](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors)